# How to convert data from database into a table in python?

Tags: python, sql

I get data from a database with  `data = cursor.fetchall()`, and the data looks as follows using

`for row in data: 
     print row`

```
(1644903L, datetime.date(2014, 6, 30), 720994L, 0L, 0L)
(1644976L, datetime.date(2014, 6, 30), 0L, 0L, 0L)
(1645045L, datetime.date(2014, 6, 30), 8600L, 0L, 0L)
```

It is 5 columns, they are

```
id int (10)
date date
revenue1 bigint(10)
revenue2 bigint(10)
revenue3 bigint(10)
```

I would like to convert `data` into a table with column names id,date,r1,r2,r3. How could I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by *table* here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I mean the table table, which can use the function such as pivot

Comment: In computer programming, that still doesn't mean anything. Excel tables let you pivot. So do many database engines. [Pandas has tables that support pivoting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html). *Your comment did nothing to clarify*.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by table. Do you mean a bunch of dictionaries? If so

```
elements = []
for row in data:
    element = {}
    element["id"] = row[0]
    element["date"] = row[1]
    element["r1"] = row[2]
    element["r2"] = row[3]
    element["r3"] = row[4]
    elements.append(element)
```

You can then access elements via elements[0]["id"] and so on. Or if the perferred access method would be moreso elements["id"][0], then...

```
elements = {}
elements["id"] = [x[0] for x in data]
elements["date"] = [x[1] for x in data]
elements["r1"] = [x[2] for x in data]
elements["r2"] = [x[3] for x in data]
elements["r3"] = [x[4] for x in data]
```

Comment: Thx. I mean the table table, which can use the function such as pivot